# Calculate b^n from a, b and a^n in modulo p

Tags: algorithm, math, number-theory

Is there any algorithm to calculate (b<sup>N</sup> mod p), given a, b, p (which is a prime) and (a<sup>N</sup> mod p) but N unknown?

A trivial way would be discrete logarithm to get N, but is there any more efficient way? Or the problem is equivalent to discrete logarithm?

Comment: Do you want to break diffie hellman?

Comment: Just in case relation to the [Diffie–Hellman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_problem) is not obvious (as it was for me), assume `a = g`, `N = x` and `b = g^y mod p`, then `b^N mod p = g^(x*y) mod p` which means finding `b^N mod p` is exactly solving the DHP.

Answer (score 5):

In general there is no way. This is because your conditions are not enough to fix the value of b<sup>N</sup> (mod p).

For example, let a = 4, b = 2, p = 5, and a<sup>N</sup> (mod p) = 1. Then N could be either 2 or 4, since 4<sup>2</sup> = 1 (mod 5) and 4<sup>4</sup> = 1 (mod 5). However, 2<sup>2</sup> = 4 (mod 5) and 2<sup>4</sup> = 1 (mod 5), so the information given is not enough to fix the value of 2<sup>N</sup>.

If you are given more information--perhaps you are told that the orders of a and b modulo p are equal, or the order of b divides the order of a, or a is a primitive root--then it is possible. But I don't know an efficient algorithm to do this.

Comment: In India, we consider ^ to be a symbol of power(exponent), hence I commented. You omitted (mod) in the first place, which I couldn't think of; +1.

Comment: Nice example (+1). If OP throws in the assumption that `a` is a primitive root (or perhaps just that `b` is in the group generated by `a`) then the problem is well-defined. Such an assumption would be fairly natural if the goal is to attack Diffie-Hellman.

Comment: @JohnColeman: I sort-of meant the case for `a` a primitive root but did not spell it out. Thanks to your nudge I have included that case and another to the possible new information.

Comment: If `a` is a primitive root then the problem *is* the [Diffie-Hellman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_problem), whose exact relation to the discrete log problem is still open. On the other hand, without some such assumption it isn't well-posed (as your example shows). There might be some interesting variation of the problem which doesn't obviously reduce to either Diffie-Hellman or discrete log.